# Ruby on Rails - Using Timezones in Rake Tasks set for Cron Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone, rake

My web application requires 6 different cron jobs to run to update timezone sensitive data within tables at 00:01:00 of each timezone.  I want to create rake tasks for each time zone.  Can I configure rake tasks to be timezone aware?  For e.g., can I do that following in a rake task:

```
namespace :db do
    task :update_EST_records => :environment do
        Time.zone = "Eastern Time (US & Canada)"
        sql = "UPDATE QUERY GOES HERE WITH CREATED_AT BETWEEN ? AND ?"
        ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
        ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql, 
            Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day.utc, 
            Time.zone.now.end_of_day.utc)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Because `:update_EST_records` depends on `:environment` task, then you have access to all your Rails environment.

You don't even have to call `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection` as long as you run the update query from your model class instead of raw SQL.

```
Model.update_all("...", ["CREATED_AT BETWEEN ? AND ?", value, value])
```